# How to challenge a user on a HTML form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, submit

looking for a simple way to ask the user if they are sure they want to submit the form and if not, to cancel the submit and return them to the form.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<form onSubmit="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false;}">

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```